# Titanium - create tableview row in a separate js

Tags: javascript, ios, uitableview, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I want to create a `TableViewRow` in a separate js called `disponibleRow.js`, but it doesn't work. I can't find the error. This is the error:

> "undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.disponibleRow.add')";

**listadoCuponesVC.js**

```
var disponibleRow = Alloy.createController('Rows/disponibleRow', cuponAux).getView();
Ti.API.debug("row: " + disponibleRow);

disponibleRow.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.API.debug('row clicked: ' + e.rowData.value);
    Alloy.createController('codigoVC', cuponAux).getView();
});

disponibles.push(disponibleRow);
```

**disponibleRow.js**

```
var fecha =  Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: args.get('date'),
    font:{fontSize:12,fontWeight:'light'},
    width:'auto',
    textAlign:'left',
    color: '#72828c',
    bottom:2,
    left:45,
    height:12
});

var puntos =  Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image:"/images/puntos_azules.png",
    width:16,
    height:16,
    right:10
});

$.disponibleRow.add(fecha);
$.disponibleRow.add(puntos);
```

**disponibleRow.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <TableViewRow height="65" id="disponibleRow">
    </TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

**EDIT:**

Now I have solved this error but `Alloy.createController` returns undefined object and I don't know why.

**EDIT 2:**

```
var disponibleRow = Alloy.createController('Rows/disponibleRow', cuponAux).getView();
```

this line return undefindet .getView() is the problem, but I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a controller you should pass an arguments object as the second argument, otherwise leave it blank. So what is cuponAux?

Example With arguments:

`var disponibleRow = Alloy.createController('Rows/disponibleRow', {arg1:"This is an argument"}).getView();`

Example Without arguments:

`var disponibleRow = Alloy.createController('Rows/disponibleRow').getView();`